NPM giving error on Node version 4.4.6 on windows machine
Error image I installed Node version 4.4.6 on new machine. This version used to work on my old machine but on new windows machine i am getting error when i issue NPM command.
Environment variable Path is C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\
I tried reinstalling and repair node after restarting machine, but it did not work

Is there a specific reason why you run a legacy version? This could be unintended. Please, provide the info for "old machine" and "new windows machine" as it could be relevant. Currently it looks like you try to use new NPM version with old Node version

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

You're running a Node version that's almost a decade old, which means that newer Javascript probably won't run on this Node if they took advantage of features introduced since then.
In this case it looks like your NPM is too new, and it's trying to use object destructuring. It looks like this was introduced in version 6.
Consider upgrading to a later version. But if you're into programming archeology you should find era-appropriate software to run on your node version.
